# Upgrade to Sbt 0.13.8 but got several warnings "detected an interpolated expression" for strings with dollar sign

Tags: scala, sbt, playframework-2.4

I upgraded my app to Play `2.4` and sbt `0.13.8`. Our code has few string variables that contain string value like "${fn}". However, after upgrading to sbt `0.13.8`, it started showing this warning:

```
possible missing interpolator: detected an interpolated expression
[warn]       var email = format.replace("${fn}", fn)
[warn]                                  ^
```

I have tried using triple quoted strings but the warnings still won't go away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be a false positive generated by the [compiler linter](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9127). You can try to either remove the linter compiler flag (look for `-Xlint` in your compiler flags) or you can upgrade to Scala 2.11.7 and sbt 0.13.9 to see if the false positive fix is picked up.

Comment: I upgraded to sbt `0.13.9` and scala `2.11.7` but it is still not working.

Comment: Oh. I removed `-Xlint` from build.sbt and it works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to keep `-Xlint` (which is generally a good idea), you can avoid the warning by writing `s"$${fn}"`.

Answer (score -1):

Scala has a standard mechanism for replacing expressions between `${...}` in strings. To make this work, you have to prepend the string with `s`. For example:

```
val fn = "someone@somewhere.com"
var email = s"${fn}" // email will be: "someone@somewhere.com"
```

Scala, or sbt, sees that you've used `${...}` in a string literal, but that there is no `s` in front of the literal. It's warning you that you might have forgotten to prepend the `s`.

Comment: Jesper, this string literal "${fn}" is meant to a string literal in our system and we want Scala to treat it like normal string literal not interpolated string.

Comment: I was just explaining why you get the warning - because that's what you asked.